# Facebook Like button is not visible on page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to add facebook like with the count on my website page. However, I am not able to see it. When I do an inspect element, I can see that facebook div has loaded without any errors.

Below is the snippet that I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link href="css/test_like.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>TEST LIKE PAGE</title></head>
    <body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.7&appId=myAppId";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="div">
  <div class="social">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://thecorbc.com" data-height="25" data-width="90" data-font="arial" data-send="false" style="height: 25px;" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
 </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is the response I get:**

```
<div class="fb-like fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://thecorbc.com" data-height="25" data-width="90" data-font="arial" data-send="false" style="height: 25px;" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" fb-iframe-plugin-query="action=like&amp;app_id=272978376409853&amp;container_width=330&amp;font=arial&amp;height=25&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fthecorbc.com%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=en_GB&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=false&amp;share=true&amp;show_faces=false&amp;size=large&amp;width=90"><span style="vertical-align: top; width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"><iframe name="f21bc3aa223b7dc" width="90px" height="25px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.7/plugins/like.php?action=like&amp;app_id=272978376409853&amp;channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FLcj5EtQ5qmD.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df12d208df1a3b78%26domain%3D%26origin%3Dfile%253A%252F%252F%252Ff193364c386dea8%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;container_width=330&amp;font=arial&amp;height=25&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fthecorbc.com%2F&amp;layout=button_count&amp;locale=en_GB&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=false&amp;share=true&amp;show_faces=false&amp;size=large&amp;width=90" style="border: none; visibility: visible; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe></span></div>
```

Comment: you did replace "myAppId" with your actual app id, right?

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I have done the exact steps as they have given in FB docs. And the result I get is same in Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: Did you ever get this right?

Comment: Nope that was a long time ago, didn't make it back then. But now I am not sure if that is still the way to do it. I ended up adding a Facebook ICON and Link on the site.